# Emitting an event from service to controller doesn't load menu on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to `$emit` an event from a service which will tell my controller when to load the menu. It works when it is loaded when the DOM is built but not $on event.

The issue is it doesn't build the menu once event is emitted on ng-repeat.

If you initially run `loadMenu()` the menu turns out fine...

```js
angular.module('app',[])

.controller('mainCtrl',function(appState, $rootScope){
  var vm = this;
  
 /*
  * This would show the menu but I only want to show it when 'loadMenu' is emitted
  * loadMenu();
  */
  
  function loadMenu() {
    vm.menuItems = [
      {name: 'settings'},
      {name: 'home'}
    ];
  }
  
  var watchMenu = $rootScope.$on('loadMenu', function() {
     console.log('LOAD THE MENU');
     loadMenu();
  });
  
  vm.emitMenu = function() {
    appState.emitMenu();
  }
})

.service('appState', function($rootScope) {
    var service = this;
    service.data = {};
    
    service.emitMenu = function() {
      $rootScope.$emit('loadMenu');
    }
    
    return service;
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
 <body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
  <div>
      <ul ng-repeat="menu in vm.menuItems">
        <li>
          <a href="">
            <span ng-bind="menu.name"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

   <button type="button" ng-click="vm.emitMenu()">Emit</button>
</div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I don't get it, why are you not loading `loadMenu()` in your watcher? Replace `console.log('LOAD THE MENU');` with `loadMenu()` for a [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/4xKMORDYxN7KrB93fvCs?p=preview)

Comment: Forgot to put that into my snippet. I've actually done this and still didn't work for me... Works perfectly fine above.

Comment: you should describe how it is used then. What AngularJS version do you have? Are you even running a local server? Do you have any errors in your console?